# Change text in data-progress-text after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a loader:

```
<div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="Loading 100 / 100" data-progress="99" style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px);"></div>
```

When it reaches 100, I want to replace that `"Loading 100 / 100"` with a new text.

I guess I need to change that `"data-progress-text"` attribute, how can I do that?

I'm trying this function but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    Pace.on('done', function() {
        $('.pace.pace-inactive').innerHTML = 'YAY!';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
$(window).load(function() {
    Pace.on('done', function() {
        $(".pace-progress").attr("data-progress-text", "new text");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use native JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('.pace-progress').dataset.progressText = value;
```

or the same with jQuery

```
$('.pace-progress').data('progressText').val(value);
```

You can also use `#attr()`, but I think is preferable to use the dedicated method.

Comment: Thanks guys! @meskobalazs the new text should go in (value), right?